# How are weak etags implemented?

Tags: http, etag

I understand that a strong etag can be a hash of an HTTP resource and that same hash means the resource is byte-to-byte equivalent. The weak etag instead means the content is semantically equivalent.

Now what I don't understand is the implementation.

It seems quite easy for a strong etag, you just do a hash of the resource, if it matches then you know the content is the same; but how do you compute content?

The first idea that comes to mind is to exclude from the computation everything that might change (and is not related to content).

---

**Let's take a simple example:**

A web-page that has a .jpg image that has been recompressed. The content will be semantically the same but the hash of the resource will change.

Then I understand in this case I should use a weak etag, but to calculate it I would need to hash only the content of the page and exclude the image from the hash.

However, if the content of the image actually changes it does not reflect in the etag.

How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you implement ETags for your page but that's how I understand ETag's usage:

### Assume we only use strong ETags:

If you provide ETags for your web page which is e.g. HTML, you would create a hash based on the page's markup. If your page contains an image, it is represented as an URL. So if you recompress the image it does not affect the page's Etag as long as the URL stays the same.

When loading the page, browser will make an extra request to load the images on your page. Requests for the images should have a separate ETag implementations. Image's ETag should change whenever byte contents of the image changes (implementations may also use modification date).

### Now for the weak ETag:

A web resource would return the same ETag if an underlying model does not change, regardless of the representation used. For example you have an endpoint displaying product information in HTML4, HTML5, plan XML and JSON - same weak ETag should be returned if the product's model does not change. Each of these representations would need to have different strong Etags.

For a weak image's Etag I can imagine the following implementation (although it sounds very impractical):
Etag is created based on uncompressed bitmap, and same Etag is served regardless of the compression parameters (compression ratio) and format (JPEG, PNG etc.). Whenever the image's content's change (on bitmap level) etag changes, but recompression does not affect it (it would affect the strong ETag).

Comment: it sounds good. How do you create the hash for the weak etag though? I mean what is the original document that you take to create the hash? Or does it need to actually be a hash anyway? It's probably something related to the specs but I can't find / understand it.

Comment: Weak etag would be based on some meta model used to generate the page. That meta model could be all dynamic bits of your page. Etag will change if the content changes, but if you e.g. change the layout and present the same content ETag will stay the same.  
BUT, in my understanding there's no gain from using weak ETags on web pages. I see it more in HTTP Web APIs delivering content in different representations.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying. I actually use it for an API now. I need weak etags so Nginx lets them go through whit Gzip activated. It does not work with strong etags since the compressed version is not bit by bit identical.